# How to retrieve states for every time step in LSTM (Tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, state, lstm

I know there were some answers related to this question, however, some methods have been deprecated and some approaches are not working.
I have a code that retrieves previous outputs but I am interested in getting hidden states information and if possible for every neuron

```
inputs = Input(shape=(3,1))
lstm, c , h = LSTM(50, activation='relu',return_state=True,return_sequences=True)(inputs)
output = Dense(1)(lstm)
```

Thank you

Comment: why don't you use `h` ?

Comment: @Andrey it returns only output for the last cell